# Can't install a package with 'revision number is empty' message

Tags: dpkg, kubuntu

In Kubuntu 17.10 I had SafeQ client installed for printing management. I needed to install two deb packages, `libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb` and `ysoft-client_4.0-87_all.deb` from [here](https://hrvooje.blogspot.hr/2015/08/print-management-safeq-and-linux.html).

However, now in Kubuntu 18.04 I can't install those two packages. For `libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb` if I do

```
sudo dpkg -i libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb
```

I get

```
dpkg: error processing archive libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 3 package 'libcrafter':
 error in 'Version' field string '0.0.2-': revision number is empty
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb
```

How can I install this, no metter what? I tried also

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb
```

'Revision number is empty' shouldn't be a reason for not installing. This package is done by [some student for his bachelor theses](https://is.muni.cz/th/409878/fi_b/) and I don't think it will be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the `libcrafter` package wasn’t built correctly: its version is given as “0.0.2-”, which isn’t an acceptable version number in Debian (as specified in [the relevant section of Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#version)). Older versions of `dpkg` accepted such version numbers, but that was fixed in version 1.18.19 (and I’m surprised you were able to install the packages in 17.10 since it has `dpkg` 1.18.24).

However this is fixable:

1. Download the existing package.
2. Extract it:

   ```
   dpkg-deb -R libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb libcrafter-0.0.2
   ```
3. Fix its version number and a couple of other issues with the package:

   ```
   sed -i 's/0.0.2-$/0.0.2-1/;s/all$/amd64/;s/java$/libs/' libcrafter-0.0.2/DEBIAN/control
   ```
4. Rebuild the package:

   ```
   dpkg-deb -b libcrafter-0.0.2 .
   ```
5. Install the resulting package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libcrafter_0.0.2-1_amd64.deb
   ```
6. Clean up:

   ```
   rm -rf libcrafter_0.0.2_all.deb libcrafter-0.0.2
   ```

   (leaving the new package for later re-use).